# Should legitimate answers be deleted because of a user's history of self promotion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, self-promotion

Here's my question in a nutshell: is deleting legitimate answers from a user an appropriate way to deal with excessive self promotion?

While looking for solutions to a problem I was facing, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18454786/1726343) mod-deleted answer. For those of you under 10k:

[image]

The author posted an earnest attempt to answer the question*, included all of the relevant code inline, and included a link to a post on what I presume was a personal website. I don't know the original reason behind the deletion, but it didn't seem like the post was spam (the linked site doesn't even have any advertising), and it wasn't off topic or unintelligible, so I flagged the post for undeletion. Here is the response:

[image]

With all due respect, I don't agree with this approach to moderation. I feel that deleting useful content simply because the author has broken rules elsewhere is counterproductive. In this specific case, the offending link could easily have been edited out of the answer (and disputed content locks/bans can always used to deal with non-cooperative users). As far as I can tell, no attempt was made to do this.

I realise that an overworked moderator might have been following up on a litany of complaints against this user and accidentally nuked some useful content along with the useless self promotion; this is totally understandable. But to insist that an on-topic, useful answer stay deleted simply because it has a link to a personal website is kind of silly (especially since the "self promotion" in the answer isn't that egregious anyway).

My personal opinion is that excessive self promotion should be edited out, useful content should be salvaged, and that deliberately throwing out the baby with the bathwater punishes the community more than the author. I wanted to get some input on how other people feel about this. Am I incorrect? Is the process of salvaging answers (and answerers) that have problems with self promotion more trouble than it is worth?

---

*I'll concede that while the posted answer does "solve" the problem, it isn't the right way to deal with the issue permanently (definitely not in production, at least). It also doesn't have a whole lot of explanation. This is irrelevant to the whole debate about deleting answers perceived to be promoting the author's interests.

Comment: 1. The fact that it's a not a good answer to begin with is *totally* relevant to the debate about deleting answers perceived to be promoting the author's interests. 2. If you think excessive self promotion should be edited out, why haven't you done that yet?

Comment: @BilltheLizard It is not a *great* answer, but it is definitely not delete-worthy. The answer was useful in diagnosing the problem for me at least. I haven't removed the link because I personally don't think it violates any rules (by itself at least). If someone feels so strongly about the link that they would delete the answer, it is preferable that they remove the link.

Comment: Whether you personally believe it or not, the link does violate a rule. From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): "However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers."